# Informatica: Target Load Issue (Relational DB SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, etl, informatica

The following error occurs when trying to load the target table (SQL Server)

**Server: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

The target table has identity column hence it has been failing. And it is not failing for one session which follows same pattern and is in same workflow.

Could you please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not connect identity column with any port in target. Leave it unconnected